# How to specify the NSDate Format in Iphone app?

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

I am trying to make a date format in such a manner hours.minutes   day/month/year

I have uses this code :

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter =[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

NSDate *dateAndtime = [NSDate date];

[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
//[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

NSString* dateforBD=[[NSString alloc]init];
dateforBD =[formatter stringFromDate:dateAndtime];
```

But this code not give me my format.

Also i have tried this code:

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease]; 
NSString *dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"E MMM d yyyy" 
                        options:0 locale:locale];

[formatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
[formatter setLocale:locale];
```

It's also give me different format. How can i achieve the required format means 13.10 21/4/2011

All the formats return in month before date. May i have used wrong way for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
     NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mma"];
     NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
     NSLog(@"date: %@", dateString);
     [dateFormat release];
```

To explore more visit http://www.stepcase.com/blog/2008/12/02/format-string-for-the-iphone-nsdateformatter/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Jennis. After some modification it works well for me with my required format. Thx for quick responce.

Answer (score 0):

for date before month use -

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"];
```

Answer (score 0):

As specified in Apple's [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) reference, the NSDateFormatter uses [Unicode Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

According to the unicode patterns, you would need the following pattern to achieve "**13.10 21/4/2011**":

```
hh:mm dd/MM/yyyy
```

So you would use this code:

```
NSDate *dateAndtime = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm dd/MM/yyyy"];

NSString *newlyFormattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateAndtime];
```

Comment: Hello Ben,I have modified the Jennis code in same way, and it works for me. Thx for responce.